# SAML Authentication Requested ( Invalid Signature Error)

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, signed, idp

I am creating signed SAML Request using below code and the certificates are cross checked to be same however getting invalid signature error on IDP , Please suggest

```
    public XmlDocument SignXML(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"" + SPCertificateLocation, SPCertificatePassword);// , X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        // set key, signing algorithm, and canonicalization method
        var signedXml = new SignedXml(xml.DocumentElement) { SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() };
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        //signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
        
        // sign whole document using "SAML style" transforms
        var reference = new Reference { Uri = string.Empty };
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);


        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert);
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // create signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // get signature XML element and add it as a child of the root element
        //signedXml.GetXml();

        //XmlElement xmlSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        //AssignNameSpacePrefixToElementTree(xmlSignature, "ds");
        
        // Add prefix "ds:" to signature
        XmlElement signature = signedXml.GetXml();
        SetPrefix("ds", signature);

        // Load modified signature back
        signedXml.LoadXml(signature);

        // this is workaround for overcoming a bug in the library
        signedXml.SignedInfo.References.Clear();

        // Recompute the signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        string recomputedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.SignatureValue);

        // Replace value of the signature with recomputed one
        ReplaceSignature(signature, recomputedSignature);

        // Append the signature to the XML document. 
        xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xml.ImportNode(signature, true), xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

        //xml.DocumentElement?.AppendChild(signedXml.GetXml());
        
        return xml;
    }
```

The code converts the XML correctly into signature enabled XML however it is showing unable to verify the authenticity of signature

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest ID="_3a6d2566-68a1-4afc-a784-c125bd94173f" Version="2.0" ForceAuthn="false" IssueInstant="2022-05-09T08:26:33Z" Destination="https://auth.pingone.com/172e7894-5cbe-456b-b451-d2585aeab74f/saml20/idp/sso" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:20630/CASCC/SamlConsume" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:20630</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>EZBisrHSVKE2zS15roaUFG0EnP3ZobisulcQXw0fO18=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>uyniiynlIP6z/g6U4qzWKdmeD8sP7majYwqDhy5n2nTDJyE8MEdaIhEJssIDeuc+VAILueMhzRV/mC4uiAZ5kgAYDa0LYnaO3673dCvuFJPgQxKbJUWYSTnfY89x/VYXsFm6kKgR2pxyGgq4VYGK9W/vvpIi+PKkYwCKtjjb8LKin/zoCPAA7UecMS9mxPeJ/ntdEfjIGTwBcoETsFRRNdVToTdVtQJjc4LBa/5FnJbGNRKFIdRDqx+wr7IbaT+08o5yl+UI2Qogly8JxeOPolVUr94rLXKyY1/n2nkXr+5LoY/sRomoCNJ11wLsMUEmg11j4J3bB93FGtlnmpwm4Q==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

As @timothy suggested i added the Id = "#" + Id

and below is the XML generated

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest ID="_35ab8f46-0ba1-4a29-a153-b02e97bf1397" Version="2.0" ForceAuthn="false" IssueInstant="2022-05-10T09:25:33Z" Destination="https://auth.pingone.com/172e7894-5cbe-456b-b451-d2585aeab74f/saml20/idp/sso" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:20630/CASCC/SamlConsume" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:20630</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference URI="#_35ab8f46-0ba1-4a29-a153-b02e97bf1397"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>0iGmT3qeJrHVXJveUe5AboRo65hxD25OjVpbbxWvbUo=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>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</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

However when i try to validate it using https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml

I get valid signature but https://console.pingone.com/ says invalid signature so may be certificates is the one i suggest it is blocking something please suggest

My Latest code looks like

```
public XmlDocument SignXML(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"" + SPCertificateLocation, SPCertificatePassword);// , X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        // set key, signing algorithm, and canonicalization method
        var signedXml = new SignedXml(xml.DocumentElement) { SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() };
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
        //signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";

        // sign whole document using "SAML style" transforms
        var reference = new Reference { Uri = "#"+_id };
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert);
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // create signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // get signature XML element and add it as a child of the root element
        //signedXml.GetXml();

        //XmlElement xmlSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        //AssignNameSpacePrefixToElementTree(xmlSignature, "ds");
        
        // Add prefix "ds:" to signature
        XmlElement signature = signedXml.GetXml();
        SetPrefix("ds", signature);

        // Load modified signature back
        signedXml.LoadXml(signature);

        // this is workaround for overcoming a bug in the library
        signedXml.SignedInfo.References.Clear();

        //var reference2 = new Reference { Uri = "#" + _id };
        //reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        //reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        //signedXml.AddReference(reference2);

        // Recompute the signature
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        string recomputedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedXml.SignatureValue);

        // Replace value of the signature with recomputed one
        ReplaceSignature(signature, recomputedSignature);

        // Append the signature to the XML document. 
        xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xml.ImportNode(signature, true), xml.DocumentElement.FirstChild);

        //xml.DocumentElement?.AppendChild(signedXml.GetXml());
        
        return xml;
    }
```

Comment: Check out my MIT licensed [SAML2 client library](https://github.com/wzychla/OldMusicBox.Saml2), in particular, the [signer](https://github.com/wzychla/OldMusicBox.Saml2/blob/master/OldMusicBox.Saml2/Signature/DefaultMessageSigner.cs).

Comment: have you uploaded the public key of your certificate in Ping One Admin Screen. possibly primary verification certificate? Have you selected the proper signature algorithm (RSA_SHA256) in PingOne?

Comment: Refer **Updating a Service Provider** in the mentioned link https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/How-do-I-change-a-verification-certificate-in-PingOne

Comment: @AkshayG I generated a self Signed Certificate Certificate.pem which I am uploading in PingOne and Certificate.p12 which i am using for signing my SAML Authn Request using its Private key from p12

Comment: you need to upload only the public key of your certificate and not the entire certificate with private key which will usually have password. just to confirm if you have done the same?

Comment: @AkshayG i have uploaded crt file that's the public key and using p12 file to get private key for signing

Comment: As per @AkshayG make sure you have uploaded the public cert to ping.  Some times they get out of sync so you can confirm your cert matches your private key as follows: openssl x509 -modulus -noout -in cert.pem | openssl md5

openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in private.pem | openssl md5

Answer (score 0):

I was able to validate your XML with perl's XML::Sig after a few changes that I had to make to XML::Sig since it does not currently support SignedInfo without an ID.

https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml also validates it fine so the issue is likely in your validation code that you did not show.

Comment: Okay Thanks @timothy 
Also I created a self signed Certificate and I am using that pfx and private key to send Auth request and on server i am using the cer file for validating, M i on right track

Comment: Please check edited question , in https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml  it says signature is valid but in pingone console i get invalid signature error

Comment: I have also validated SAML Authn Request with certificate on below URL , it says valid request https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php @timothy